# Is there a way to tell browser metadata of playing media content

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find how to tell the browser details about media content thats playing (video or audio). For example, if I play content on https://music.apple.com, the Now Playing widget in macOS Control Center will show the title and album of playing content.

I've been trying to do it with a song that contains all metadata (the song was purchased from the iTunes Store), but the Control Center only shows the title of the page.

Here is what I've tried:

```html
<audio controls >
    <source src="./01 Pompeii.m4a" type="audio/mp4">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer with this page: https://web.dev/media-mobile-web-video-playback/#customize-media-notifications

Basically, doing the following provides metadata information for the Control Center to show:

```js
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
audio.addEventListener('play', function() {
    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
        title: 'Pompeii',
        artist: 'Bastille'
    });
});
```